# Disable main maven artifact install in local repo but not secondary artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which generates 2 artifacts.

1 main artifact - a war (packaging element in pom.xml) and

1 secondary artifact - a jar (using maven-jar-plugin) comprised of subset of classes that needs to be shared with other projects.

When I run mvn install, I need to only install the jar artifact and skip the war, and also generate the pom so that the installed jar can be imported by other projects.

I can generate the war and jar artifacts, but both the war and jar are installed in my local maven repo and when I try to import from another project it only shows the war.

I tried a few approaches but I have not been able to solve this.

---

```
<project>  
<groupId>com.company.component</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
           <configuration>
               <includes>
                   <include>com/company/component/common/*.class</include>
               </includes>
               <finalName>component-</finalName>
               <classifier>common</classifier>
           </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please give us your code. Also, tell us what you have done till now.

Comment: I would highly recommend to review your project structure so that all the shared business logic goes into separate jar project and web-specific content stays in the current war project.

Comment: @AdityaRamkumar added some sample code where I'm stuck.

Comment: @SergeyPauk That was the first solution that came to mind. But I would like to solve this with the existing structure if possible.